# When tabpage add controls like form, how set form owner

Tags: c#, winforms

when i individual add two forms to two pages controls,
how set form owner?
Because owner is empty, could not set data from form's event to another form's textbox text, how slove it, please help me .

-main form-
//tabpage add controls

```
private void TestForm2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var DataUpdate = new DataUpdate();
    var DataUpdate = new TestForm3();
    DataUpdate.TopLevel = false;
    //DataUpdate.Visible = true;
    //DataUpdate.Top = 0;
    //DataUpdate.Left = 0;
    DataUpdate.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    DataUpdate.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(DataUpdate);


    //var SystemSetting = new SystemSetting();
    var SystemSetting = new TestForm4();
    SystemSetting.TopLevel = false;
    //SystemSetting.Visible = true;
    //SystemSetting.Top = 0;
    //SystemSetting.Left = 0;
    SystemSetting.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    SystemSetting.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    tabPage2.Controls.Add(SystemSetting);
    SystemSetting.Show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are asking. "Does not work" is a description that does not help much. What do you *expect* to happen? What happens *instead*? What did you do to get there?

Comment: now is better??

Answer (score 1):

```
// In your TestForm3, 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TestForm4 frm = new TestForm4();
  frm.owner=this;
  frm.Show();
}
 // In your TestForm4,
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TestForm3 mainForm=(TestForm3)this.owner;
  mainForm.LabelText = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but when i use tabcontrol & add form to page that can't work.

Comment: i set global TestForm3 parameter and In my TestForm4 is work. thank you